# Angular 2 - Getting a parameter from route with the forward slash (/)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a route in my module's router similar to

```
{
    path: 'reset-password/:code',
    component: ResetPasswordComponent
}
```

The code is generated from the server and contains quite a few forward slash (/) character and possibly a plus (+) character with other special characters as well.

A sample URL looks something like

> http://localhost:53796/reset-password/gaUSiYYGs9DoRGnbh3oxTDzVBKoodNOtIhMTupQ9LBgEd2uVyJknw0hNQOCgcaqxpaQW4HTtYBDPzt/GnDzT6QhiCsG3W1c19CpfF/BaFkW3lqEXym9dQ0uoDiyIS6M81yiKAO3jBO3ysCtqQISvqrVllpKS66uvCPWbbqyvcGi0Tg27e0e78NUB1NaGDioymrfubsJ7AuD2EcI5gcg

This should map to the code property in my component's Activated route but it breaks the page and user is redirected to a 404 (not found) component which makes sense because it considers it a route with multiple parameters which does not exists.

The `code` is coming from the email link so its very unlikely that I could manipulate it, how can I receive it in my component without breaking it?

Edit: Including the code of how I am trying to get the code in my component

```
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.code = params["code"];
    });
```

Where `route: ActivatedRoute`

Comment: can you encode your url to '%2f'. this should work

Comment: The user clicks the link in the email and which directly takes him to this reset-password route with the code, when can I encode it in this flow? @RahulSingh

Comment: @AliBaig make use of Router Router resolve and inside there you can sue Url serializer https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer

Comment: @AliBaig can you list that method where it is fired and how you do that

Comment: @RahulSingh Sure ok, I will try using the the UrlSerializer. Btw, I have included the code where I am trying to fetch it from route in my edit

Comment: @AliBaig code where you send it to the route like you will have a route.navigate(//something )

Comment: @RahulSingh It comes from the link in an email generated by the server (ASP.NET MVC using `UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken`)

Comment: okay then router resolve and url seralizer can do the trick